# Erlang variables management

Tags: variables, memory, erlang, allocation

Let's take this Erlang example :

```
X=2, 
L=[1, X].
```

what happens exactely in the memory :
1-in the first line allocate memory space for X and in the second line allocate another memory space for X, 
2-in the first line allocate memory space for X and in the second create just a tag toward X

Answer (score 0):

I think erlang sets aside memory for a list containing two elements, namely 1 and 2.  In other words, the value 2 exists in memory in two places.